# what is the error in the following code?

Tags: linux, c

showing segmentation fault core dumped 
copying content of multiple files to one file 
the question is Write a C program that takes a string as an argument and search for all the files that begins with that name present in the current working directory and merge the content of all those files to a new file with name (Mfile) and returns a file descriptor for the new file. you can watch my code at this link 
[this is the link to my code](http://txt.do/drhqh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fp=fopen("dr->d_name","r");
```

Above code should be rewritten as `fp=fopen(dr->d_name,"r");`.

C always treat double quoted values as strings instead variables.